# XAML: Binding fiasco with a DataTemplate within a ListView within a DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, binding, combobox, relativesource

Hi I got a dataTemplate for a ViewModel.

Within this DataTemplate I got a ListView bound to a collection of the template and there In I wan't to be able to set a property of the items in the collection.

The available settings of the property is in another collection in the original ViewModel but I'm having a hard time binding to it.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel}">

    <!-- Some irrelevant property bindings -->

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource SOMEAPPROPRIATERELATIVESOURCE}, 
                                           Path=AvailablePropertiesCollection}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TheProperty}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Is there some good way to get the binding to the item of the top level DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would want to use:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, 
    Path=DataContext.AvailablePropertiesCollection}"
```

This binds to the AvailablePropertiesCollection on the ListView's data context.

Comment: So the ListView has the item wrapped in the DataTemplate as a DataContext. Makes sense, I'll check it out and then give you the right answer if it works.

Comment: @Ingó - Yeah, anything in a DataTemplate gets a new "data context". In this case it would be the item from ItemsSource. Sounds like you need to get the data context of the ListView, which is what I describe.

Comment: Works perfectly, so simple I should ahve figured that out. Well it takes a lifetime to master XAML. Thank you.

Comment: Trying to award the bounty gives me a 23 hour notice, do you know how this works?

Comment: @Ingó - I think you have to wait a day or two, but no worries or hurry.